# change wifi connection with network-manager(nmcli) and user www-data

Tags: wireless-networking, networkmanager

I [initalially asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1221049/nmcli-add-wlan-connection-through-apache2-user) with a wrong user. I got closer to the result but still have no success.

When I execute

```
sudo -H -u www-data bash -c 'nmcli d wifi connect "SSID" password "password"
```

I get the following result

```
Fehler: Neue Verbindung konnte nicht hinzugefügt und aktiviert werden: (32) No session found for uid 33 (unknown)
```

I somehow need the www-data user to be able to use the nmcli tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUDO.

As root, use visudo (or sudoedit or vi /etc/sudoers) and add a line near the beginning of the file like

```
www-data   ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/nmcli
```

Then call the command sudo nmcli...

Fairly authorative information on the sudo command can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).  Details of the sudoers config file can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

Comment: thank you! saved my day. There is still a tiny issue. I use the networkmanager under raspbian. changing the connection works, but I get an unknown error, eventhough it does work. any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Pi (and don't know Raspian spevifically)